# Vector searching

Tags: c++, algorithm, search, stdvector, stdstring

Basically I have a load of words in my string vector `vector<string> words`.

I need to make a function that searches for all the words with "`ly`" throughout my vector and return them, for example (`golly, helpfully, mostly, nearly`).

How do I use the `std::find_if` function to do this or is there any other way that I can do this?

I also need to find words that are longer than `7` letters in my vector, do I still use the `std::find_if` function with `>=7` or something else?

Comment: If you fill your question with a [mcve] and point out where you have problems specifically, it'll be easier to answer.

Comment: It is explained in [the docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find). Just use if with the predicate that uses `std::string::find` to check if the string contains desired characters

Comment: To find words that are **longer than** 7 letters, you should use `> 7`, not `>= 7`.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, there is a more appropriate algorithm in the standard library called [`std::copy_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) than the `std::find_if` (for what you have asked).

Secondly, you need to get a different list of words asper different cases. This sounds like having a [template function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template) which wraps the `std::copy_if` and also provide a way to give the custom compare (e.g. a [lambda function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)) functionalities.

Therefore I would suggest something like as follows:

```
#include <algorithm> // std::copy_if
#include <iterator>  // std::cbegin, std::cend


template<typename Container, typename Predicate>
auto getElelmentsOf(const Container& container, const Predicate condition) /* noexcept */
{
    Container result;
    std::copy_if(std::cbegin(container), std::cend(container), std::back_inserter(result),
        condition);
    return result;
}
```

Now you could write something like

```
// all the words with "ly"
const auto words_with_ly = [](const auto& ele) {
    return ele.find(std::string{ "ly" }) != std::string::npos;
};
const auto elemtsOfLy = getElelmentsOf(words, words_with_ly);  // function call


// find words that are longer than 7 letters
const auto words_with_size_7_more = [](const auto& ele) { return ele.size() > 7; };
const auto elemtsOfsize7More = getElelmentsOf(words, words_with_size_7_more);  // function call
```

**([See a Live Demo Online](https://godbolt.org/z/qj7W5Y))**

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`std::copy_if`](https://cpprefjp.github.io/reference/algorithm/copy_if.html) to get all elements that satisfy some conditions.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm> // for std::copy_if
#include <iterator> // for std::back_inserter

using std::vector;
using std::string;

int main(void) {
    vector<string>words={
        "golly", "hoge", "lyric", "helpfully",
        "mostly", "abcdefg", "nearly", "terrible"
    };
    vector<string> res_ly, res_7;

    // get all words that contains "ly"
    std::copy_if(words.begin(), words.end(), std::back_inserter(res_ly),
        [](const string& x){ return x.find("ly") != string::npos; });

    // get all words that are longer than 7 letters
    std::copy_if(words.begin(), words.end(), std::back_inserter(res_7),
        [](const string& x){ return x.length() > 7; });

    // print what we got
    std::cout << "words with \"ly\":\n";
    for (const string& s : res_ly) std::cout << "  " << s << '\n';
    std::cout << "\nwords longer than 7 letters:\n";
    for (const string& s : res_7) std::cout << "  " << s << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
words with "ly":
  golly
  lyric
  helpfully
  mostly
  nearly

words longer than 7 letters:
  helpfully
  terrible
```

If you want to use `std::find_if`, you can repeat searching like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm> // for std::find_if
#include <iterator> // for std::next

using std::vector;
using std::string;

int main(void) {
    vector<string>words={
        "golly", "hoge", "lyric", "helpfully",
        "mostly", "abcdefg", "nearly", "terrible"
    };
    vector<string> res_ly;

    // get all words that contains "ly"
    for (vector<string>::iterator start = words.begin(); ;) {
        vector<string>::iterator next = std::find_if(start, words.end(),
            [](const string& x){ return x.find("ly") != string::npos; });
        if (next == words.end()) {
            break;
        } else {
            res_ly.push_back(*next);
            start = std::next(next, 1);
        }
    }

    // print what we got
    std::cout << "words with \"ly\":\n";
    for (const string& s : res_ly) std::cout << "  " << s << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I could suggest the following solution.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

std::vector<std::string> copy_strings( const std::vector<std::string> &v, const std::string &s )
{
    auto present = [&s]( const auto &item ) 
    {
        return item.find( s ) != std::string::npos; 
    };

    auto n = std::count_if( std::begin( v ), std::end( v ), present );
                            
    std::vector<std::string> result;
    result.reserve( n );
    
    std::copy_if( std::begin( v ), std::end( v ), 
                  std::back_inserter( result ),
                  present );
                  
    return result;                
}

int main() 
{
    std::vector<std::string> v =
    {
        "golly", "helpfully", "mostly", "nearly"
    };
    
    auto result = copy_strings( v, "ly" );
    
    for (const auto &item : result )
    {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
golly helpfully mostly nearly
```

Comment: In order to `result.reserve( n );` you are iterating over the vector once. Then do once again iteration for finding words. Not sure about the in practice, how performant it would be.

Comment: @Const Dynamically reallocating memory can take more type then just traversing already allocated memory.